# Task reports IsCompleted but still blocks on Result?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency

I've encountered some strage behaviour using the .Net 4 class **System.Threading.Tasks**. It's best demonstrated by this example:

```
var t = FunctionThatReturnsTaskAsync();
Trace.TraceInformation("Completed: " + t.IsCompleted);
return t.Result;
```

Output: "*Completed: true*", but the code (once in a few thousand runs) then blocks at t.Result forever. It neither returns or throws an exception. How can this be!

The task returned is some times fast to complete so it's no surprise that it can be completed on the second line. The mystery is why t.Result is blocking.

Comment: How is that function implemented?

Comment: FunctionThatReturnsTaskAsync? It ends up calling  Task<T>.Factory.StartNew(() => {}, CancellationToken.None).

Comment: Strange. Can you post a minimal example that exhibits the problem?

Comment: @CodeInChaos, minimal example would be fine, but since this happens "once in a few thousand runs", I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: @svick Such a sample would call this code a million times in a loop, so the problem is likely to occur.

Comment: The Task class doesn't have a Result property.  The Start() method call is completely invisible.  Post code that can actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the call-stack that is active when the problem is occurring? My guess is that we will find a bug in there.

Comment: For some reason, I am no longer able to reproduce this. I'll try some more and see if I can create some minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

Async methods return Tasks themselves, you might have a Task< Task < T > > and the inner task returns before 'finishing' due to 'async', and the outer Task<> thinks it is complete.

See Stephen Toub's blog posts on this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/08/10265476.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Allow me to pull out a relevant quote:

> To understand this effect, we need to remember how async methods operate.  When you invoke an async method, it starts running synchronously.  If the method doesn’t have any awaits in it, or if all of the awaits in the method are on awaitables that are already completed by the time they’re awaited, then the method will run entirely synchronously.  However, when the method encounters the first await that yields, the async method returns.  In the case of an async method that returns a Task or a Task, the method at this point returns the Task or Task that represents the async method’s execution, and the caller can use that task to wait synchronous (e.g. Wait()) or asynchronously (e.g. await, ContinueWith) for the method to asynchronously complete.  In the case of a void method, though, no handle is handed back.  Async void methods are thus often referred to as “fire and forget.”

Comment: The question specifically asks about .ENET 4.0 and you explain .NET 5?!